# How to close QDialog Window with pushButton?

Tags: python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

i am currently working on this gui project. and i create a settings window but i cant make it close after pushing the buttons. i tried use `self.close()`, `self.accept()`, `self.reject()` methods. When i click the button nothing happens. Here is my code, which is simplified :

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QLineEdit, QWidget, QMenu, QMenuBar, QAction, 
                            QMainWindow, QApplication, QDialog, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout)
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize, QRect, QMetaObject, QCoreApplication, QObject, Qt


class Ui_Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui_Dialog, self).__init__()


    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(100, 100)
        self.verticalLayout= QVBoxLayout(Dialog)

        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit(Dialog)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")        
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.pushButton = QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.pushButton_2 = QPushButton(Dialog)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)


        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.save)
    

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)



    def save(self):
        global setting
        setting = self.lineEdit.text()
        self.done(1)
        self.accept()
        self.deleteLater()
        self.destroy()
        self.reject()
        self.close()



    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "Settings"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Save"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Cancel"))



class Ui_MainWindow(QObject):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1250, 609)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QSize(833, 600))
        self.centralWidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.menubar = QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 906, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuOptions = QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuOptions.setObjectName("menuOptions")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.actionSettings = QAction(MainWindow)       
        self.actionSettings.setObjectName("actionSettings")
        self.menuOptions.addAction(self.actionSettings)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuOptions.menuAction())

        self.actionSettings.triggered.connect(self.preferences)
       

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)



    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "closinDialogSample"))
        self.menuOptions.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Options"))
        self.actionSettings.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Settings"))


    def preferences(self):
        self.preferences_dialog = QDialog()
        self.preferences_dialog.ui = Ui_Dialog()
        self.preferences_dialog.ui.setupUi(self.preferences_dialog)
        self.preferences_dialog.setAttribute(Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        self.preferences_dialog.setModal(True)
        self.preferences_dialog.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Do not try to mimic the behavior of pyuic. If you create a subclass of a Qt widget, then just use it. Add `self.setupUi(self)` in the `__init__` of those ui classes and directly use them: `self.preferences_dialog = Ui_Dialog()`. Also, `Ui_MainWindow` should inherit from QMainWindow, not QObject, then `mainWindow = Ui_MainWindow()`

Comment: Well, it fix the issue. Thank you very much. QtDesigner generates the code this way, and i directly use it. thanks again.

Comment: No, Designer (pyuic) does *not* generate the code that way. Either you're trying to mimic its behavior (which is pointless as said above), or you're editing the file (which is considered a bad practice). If you're using pyuic, then do not edit those files (read how to properly [use Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html)), if not, just create subclasses of Qt widgets and directly use them.

Comment: I am editing the file.

Comment: Then, don't. Rebuild the files with pyuic, create a new file as the main script and follow the directions in the link above.

Comment: My advice - never rely on connecting slots by name. This is such a fragile design... Your program will fall apart whenever you rename some signals or slots. Just do not do it. It is best to forget that such a mechanism even exsits.

Comment: @HiFilethebestfilemanager the OP is not actually using what `connectSlotsByName` provides, that code is automatically added by pyuic. Even if that was used, it wouldn't have worked, since the slots must be implemented in the target widget (the argument of `setupUi()`), and since only the base classes were used, no compatible function would have been found.